# Throttling events based on previous occurrence

Tags: c#, system.reactive, tpl-dataflow

I have this test method

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task MethodName(){
        var strings = new BufferBlock<string>();
        var ints = new BufferBlock<int>();
        ConcurrentStack<Tuple<string,int> > concurrentStack=new ConcurrentStack<Tuple<string, int>>();
        var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<Tuple<string,int>,string>(async tuple => {
            var formattableString = $"{tuple.Item2}-{tuple.Item1}-{Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}";
            if (concurrentStack.TryPeek(out var result) && Equals(result, tuple)){
                WriteLine($"Await -> {formattableString}");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            concurrentStack.Push(tuple);
            await DoAsync(tuple);
            WriteLine(formattableString);
            return formattableString;
        });
        var joinBlock = new JoinBlock<string,int>();
        var dataflowLinkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions(){PropagateCompletion = true};
        joinBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock,dataflowLinkOptions);
        strings.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target1,dataflowLinkOptions);
        ints.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target2,dataflowLinkOptions);

        strings.Post("a");
        strings.Post("a");
        strings.Post("b");
        strings.Post("b");
        ints.Post(1);
        ints.Post(1);
        ints.Post(2);
        ints.Post(1);

        strings.Complete();

        transformBlock.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<string>());
        await transformBlock.Completion;
    }
```

which outputs

```
  15:36:53.2369|1-a-28  
  15:36:53.2369|Await -> 1-a-28  
  15:36:54.2479|1-a-28  
  15:36:54.2479|2-b-38  
  15:36:54.2479|1-b-38
```

I am looking to throttle this operation in a way that if the previous item is the same as the current to wait for a certain amount of time. I would like to use this flow in a parallel scenario and my guess is that RX extensions could be the solution here as I do not feel my approach is correct although it seems to produce the correct results.

**UPDATE - CONCRETE EXAMPLE**

In comments @Enigmativity requested to provide examples of my sources and transforms, so I think the real implementation is the best fit to this.

```
_requestHandlerDatas = new BufferBlock<IRequestHandlerData>(executionOption);
_webProxies = new TransformBlock<WebProxy, PingedWebProxy>(async webProxy => {
    var isOnline =await requestDataflowData.Pinger.IsOnlineAsync(webProxy.Address).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return new PingedWebProxy(webProxy.Address, isOnline);
}, executionOption);
var joinBlock = new JoinBlock<IRequestHandlerData, WebProxy>(new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions { Greedy = false });
_transformBlock = new TransformBlock<Tuple<IRequestHandlerData, WebProxy>, TOut>(async tuple => {
    await requestDataflowData.LimitRateAsync(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var @out = await requestDataflowData.GetResponseAsync<TOut>(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2).ConfigureAwait(false);
    _webProxies.Post(tuple.Item2);
    _requestHandlerDatas.Post(tuple.Item1);
    return @out;
}, executionOption);
var dataflowLinkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions(){PropagateCompletion = true};
joinBlock.LinkTo(_transformBlock,dataflowLinkOptions,tuple => ((PingedWebProxy)tuple.Item2).IsOnline);
joinBlock.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<Tuple<IRequestHandlerData, WebProxy>>(),dataflowLinkOptions,tuple =>
    !((PingedWebProxy) tuple.Item2).IsOnline);
_requestHandlerDatas.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target1,dataflowLinkOptions);
_webProxies.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target2,dataflowLinkOptions);
```

So, first I am posting data to `_webProxies` which verifies that I have a working proxy and if so it links it together with my `_requestHandlerDatas` in a `_transformBlock` that will use them to call another service. When that call returns I am releasing both the used parameters (proxy, handlerData) back to their pools and output the `TOut` for further processing from another block. My goal is to delay the webservice calls from the same proxy,handlerData combination.

Comment: Throttling in Dataflow can be done with a `BoundedCapacity`, 
or a `MaxDegreeOfParrallelism`. To get the blocks upstream of the `TransformBlock` set all the blocks `BoundedCapacity` to a value other than the default, `Unbounded`. `await`ing a delay will delay the instance of your processing but if the block is unbound or has a MDOP greater than one your processing will continue. Can you elaborate on exactly what kind of back pressure or delay you need?

Comment: Can you explain what the semantics are of the stream that you need? Can you please examples of your source and what the changes should be to the output?

Comment: Both BufferBlocks async output data from long operations such as WebService calls and using their data I want to call a third WebService but need to spare resources and delay same parameters calls by a predefined period of time.

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris - Could you please provide examples of the source data and examples of the output after it is transformed?

Comment: @Enigmativity I update my original post, I hope this info is what you looking for.

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris - No, you're missing my point. I want sample input data and the required output. I want to know what values get produced at what time for the source and what the output would be and when.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am sorry I cannot understand. My input is a WebProxy class and an IRequestHandlerData concrete implementation to be used from the DelegatingHandler of an HttpClient and my output is a class that will be constructed by deserializing the response of the HttpClient call. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris - At 1 second 5 is produced, then two seconds later 3, and 5 after that 10. The output should be 5 when 5 is produced, 3 two seconds after the 3 is produced and finally 10 when it is produced. That kind of thing. I don't need to know about your actual sources or your actual classes.

Comment: @Enigmativity to add to my previous comment. I have a pool of proxy addresses which change often and pushing them to the flow. The flow validates them and combines them with `IRequestHandlerData` implementations which come from another pool. A `IRequestHandlerData` may contain properties like 'Credentials', 'ServiceUri' etc. The webproxy pool is store in a db and is modified from end users. All output service calls must operate under a fixed delayed (10sec) and duplicate under a configurable delay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163135/discussion-between-apostolis-bekiaris-and-enigmativity).

Comment: @Enigmativity the input comes is already stored on the db so it comes to the flow immediately but can be modified at random times while the flow is recurring.  All output service calls must operate under a fixed delayed (10sec) and duplicate under a configurable delay.

Comment: Still looking for clarification. What about the original implementation you posted either 1) does not behave the way you want 2) Fails at large or 3) you're looking for a different approach to?

Comment: @JSteward I have a pool of proxies and a pool of webservices which differ in items count. I want to combine them in a way that I will call a each webservice from a different proxy on a fixed delay (x sec). For the cases that the previous call to a certain webservice was made from the same proxy I want to introduce a different delay (2*x sec ). My flow is recurring after each webservice calls it feeds back the input pools.

Comment: In addition the input pools count is constantly modified as new proxies and webservices added by the end users. Of course I can go with any approach that can model a solution to this problem and not bounded to TPL or RX though my feeling is that those two are the winners. Have I managed to completely clarify my problem?

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris Ok I think I'm starting to understand your requirements. But what is it that the first implementation doesn't accomplish? It looks like it checks all the boxes unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @JSteward the scenario is a bit complex for my experience and real time tests showed that i need lock the ConcurrentBag which led me to believe that the implementation is not entirely correct.

Comment: _lock the `ConcurrentBag`_? It sounds like that might be a better question, can you simplify the code that led you to that conclusion and submit a question related solely to that? Your current question seems to get broader and broader, it might be time to re-frame it into something more answerable. You really shouldn't ever need to synchronize around a `ConcurrentBag`, i.e. the consumers/producers of the bag shouldn't be tightly coupled to what's exactly in the bag. Otherwise you could just be using `IEnumerable<T>` with a lock.